# Using Retrofit with Rails API

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails-4, gson, retrofit, active-model-serializers

I am developing an Android application. I decided to use Square's Retrofit library which fits my requirements. However I am facing with **deserialization problem**. My backend is written in Rails 4 by using `rails-api` gem. `active-model-serializer` generates this kind of JSON (JSONs have an root element):

```
{"user":{"id":1,"name":"Saygun","github_url":"www.github.com/saygun" }}
```

Here is how I initialize `retrofit`.

```
public class User {

    private String mId;
    private String mName;
    private String mGithubUrl;

    public String getId() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.mId = id;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.mName = name;
    }

    public String getGithubUrl(String url) {
        this.mGithubUrl = url;
    }
}


public interface RestService {

    @GET("/users/{id}")
    void getUser(@Path("id") int id, Callback<User> cb);
}
```

`Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
         .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
         .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateTypeAdapter())
         .create();`

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(BuildConfig.API_ENDPOINT)
        .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
        .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
        .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
        .build();

RestService service = restAdapter.create(RestService.class);
service.getUser(1, new Callback<User>() {
     @Override
     public void success(User user, Response response) {
          //User is null
     }

     @Override
     public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

     }
});
```

Is there anyone can show me what I am missing. Why does `retrofit` cannot create user?

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

As i think you should use the same name for your fields as  API class
and implements Serializable in your client class .

something like this :

```
public class User implements Serializable {

public String id ;
public String name;
public String github_url;

}
```

or you also can use  @SerializedName("serialized_name")

like this :

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName()
    private String mId;

    @SerializedName()
    private String mName;

    @SerializedName()
    private String mGithubUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution (kotlin version)

```kotlin
class UserModel(
    val id: Long,
    val name: String,
    val githubUrl: String
)

class UserResponse(
    @SerializedName("user") val model: UserModel
)

class PagedUserListResponse(
    val metaData: PageMetaData,
    @SerializedName("users") val items: List<UserModel>
) : PageMeta by metaData

interface PageMeta {
    val totalPages: Int
    val currentPage: Int
    val count: Int
    val previousPage: Int
    val nextPage: Int
}

class PageMetaData(
    override val totalPages: Int,
    override val count: Int,
    override val previousPage: Int,
    override val nextPage: Int,
    override val currentPage: Int
) : PageMeta

interface UserAPICaller {

    @GET("users")
    suspend fun index(@Query("page") page: Int?, @Query("per_page") perPage: Int?): PagedUserListResponse

    @POST("users")
    suspend fun create(@Body request: UserRequest): UserResponse

    @PATCH("users/{id}")
    suspend fun update(@Path("id") id: Long, @Body request: UserRequest): UserResponse
}
```